# Why isn't this server/client connection working?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm setting up my first server with node.js, but I don't know how to connect a client and that server. I don't want to use jquery, and all the questions I could find about this involved jquery or were about different languages. Does anyone know how to do this?

Edit: I have a connection between the server and client, but the response has nothing in it. The code for my server is [here](https://repl.it/@GameMaster1928/Server), and the code for my client is [here](https://repl.it/@GameMaster1928/Stuff) (in the folder "Multiplayer").

Comment: Well, if you find a jQuery solution, you can translate it into JavaScript pretty easily - jQuery is JavaScript after all.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @KevinB yup, it's a duplicate. I'll flag it.

Comment: Now I've set up the server, but it isn't working. The client requests and gets a response, but the response has nothing in it.

Comment: I solved the problem on the [Javascript Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this to setup a Node.js HTTP server listenning on port 8080.

The client will send GET requests using AJAX.

---

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      // Create a function callback, called every time readyState changes
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
        // When the response has been received with status 200
        // Update the element div#response-holder
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
        {
          var txtDisplay = elem document.getElementById("response-holder")
          txtDisplay.innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      };

      // Send a GET request to /api, asynchronously
      xhttp.open("GET", "/api", true);
      xhttp.send();
    <script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="response-holder"></div>
  </body>
</html>"
```

**server.js**

```
// Load the http and fs (filesystem) modules
var app = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");

// Serve the "/index.html" home page on port 8080
app.createServer(function (req, resp)
{
  fs.readFile("index.html", function(err, data)
  {
    resp.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    resp.write(data);
    resp.end();
  }
  );
}
).listen(8080);

// Also answer to GET requests on "/api"
app.get('/api', function(req, resp)
{
  var responseStr = "Hello World!";
  resp.status(200);
  resp.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
  return resp.send(responseStr);
}
);
```

Here is a W3Schools tutorial on AJAX:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

You may do that with vanilla JavaScript, using **Fetch API**.

Assuming that Node will provide you some URLs, you can get, post, etc., through fetching them.

More on how that works here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score -2):

TCP connection between client and Node server will be the option. Here's a sample code snippet:

```
var ser = require('ser');

var clientSer = new net.Socket();
clientSer.connect(1220, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write('Hello, Connection Established!');
});

clientSer.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
    client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
});

clientSer.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Node tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_intro.asp